# What is Dune Bashing?

Tags: dubai, terminology, deserts, safari, dunes

I was looking at a website that is offering 40 to 45 minute "Dune Bashing" in a desert tour. What is this "bashing"?

Comment: it's called **wadi bashing**, not dune bashing.

Comment: Writing negative reviews about [Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))

Comment: It is definitely called dune bashing, whatever other names might exist for it. @Fattie

Comment: @Nij - fair enough!

Answer (score 27):

Take powerful SUVs and ATVs and bash some sand dunes in a desert!

[image]

Courtesy: [https://visitabudhabi.ae](https://visitabudhabi.ae/DataFolder/Images/Thumbnails/2000x800/Dune-Bashing-Hero-01.jpg)

[image]

Courtesy: [https://visitabudhabi.ae](https://visitabudhabi.ae/DataFolder/Images/Thumbnails/900x600/dune-bashing-0007.JPG)

Comment: One of those cases where a picture says more than a thousand words.

Comment: I presume they change the air filters on those trucks after each excursion...

Comment: @chrylis hah, you obviously never visited middle east

Comment: @Lope (Joking.)